# how to play video in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

hi i have a list of items in that both video url and image url i am displaying that as below

HTML code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="news_image" ng-repeat="image in items.media">
    <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" ng-if="image.type === 'img'" />
    <video ng-if="image.type === 'video'" width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source ng-src="{{image.src}}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

and angular js code

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.items = {
    "media": [{
        "type": "img",
        "src": "http://images/2015/May/161887.jpg"
    }, {
        "type": "video",
        "src": "http:/video/2015/May/161887.mp4",
    }]
};
```

});

The problem is the images are working properly but the video is not working. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code. Video src is wrong.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.items = {
    "media": [{
        "type": "img",
        "src": "http://images/2015/May/161887.jpg"
    }, {
        "type": "video",
        "src": "http://video/2015/May/161887.mp4",
    }]
};
});
```

Comment: There's also a trailing comma.

Comment: yes.. it is fine if you leave it.. but everyone likes proper coding :)

Comment: Can you please let me know the wrong thing in this code. the video url is not correct this is a sample i am using some other  url